# Show with mathematical induction using n:

Tags: induction

If n men and n women meet in order to marry then there are exactly n! different arrangements such that each man is married with exactly one woman and vice versa.

Hint: Give numbers to the men and women from 1 to n and denote an arrangement as n- tuple where position i stores number j if the man with number i is married with woman with number j. For the inductive step, focus on George and consider how many possibilities exist for George to marry a woman. Then combine this with the arrangements for the remaining men and women.

Any help will be appreciate-able.

I took the n tuple as

```
 f(n) = (1, 2, 3, 4, ......... n)
 but can i use the induction as
 n! or 1.2.3 .....n.(n+1)!
```

I do not understand that how i will build the relation.

Comment: Maybe you are taking such downvotes because you didn't state any of your own attempts.

Comment: i update my question. And ofcourse trying get it. But little help may be get me to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a pain it is to prove this by induction.  Numbering the brides and grooms, and then giving an ordering of the grooms by bride, seems much more straightforward.

I assume you already have the basis step.  The induction step can be accounted for as follows.  Suppose you already have $k!$ arrangements for $n = k$; in these arrangements, let the brides and grooms be denoted by $\{b_i\}, \{g_i\}, i = 1, 2, \ldots$.

Given any one of the $k!$ arrangements of the $n = k$ brides and grooms, we can introduce $b_{k+1}$ and $g_{k+1}$ in $k+1$ ways.  One way is for the two to marry each other.  Then there are $k$ different ways for both of them to marry one of the first $k$ brides and grooms.  (You need to figure out how to show this.)

Since this reasoning maps each arrangement of $k$ brides and grooms to $k+1$ arrangements of $k+1$ brides and grooms, and the arrangements are distinct (you need to figure out how to show this, too), there must be $k+1$ times as many arrangements of $k+1$ brides and grooms as there are of $k$ brides and grooms, and the induction step is shown.

Comment: "What a pain it is to prove this by induction" You can literally prove it in two lines using induction.

Comment: Well, OK, "pain" is an overstatement (I think to make it transparent to a student requires more than two lines, unless you have a more elegant approach).  But the direct way is rather simpler.